# iphone camera zoom issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    imageView.image = nil;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
        picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        // picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        picker.allowsEditing = NO;
        picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
        picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
       [picker.view addSubview:overlay];
       [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I have an issue when open camera picker picker seems like little zoom in but when take photo , photo is not exactly same as see in camera view.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
picker.cameraViewTransform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
```

after

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

Comment: first line getting error assigning to CGAAfflinetransform from incompatiable type int

Comment: It is also not woring i in my table there is a pen and pencil and i fouz only pen i can only see the pen but when take photo i got image with pen and pencil.